# Setting up an IoT backend using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, amazon-cognito

I am trying to setup the backend services for consumer IoT device which includes the following activities (4 main high level services). These services are ultimately consumed by a web application or from mobile application through REST API's.
Instead of reinventing the wheel, I am evaluating AWS offerings which should partially or fully match these services. With my limited knowledge and research, I was able to find few AWS offering that matches, however they may not be complete and the most appropriate ones, and hence need advice. Below are the services and my findings.

1. Self user registration - *Cognito with User Pools*
2. Device provisioning (Adding/attaching one or more devices to a user) - *No idea on how to handle this with AWS. Can we add the devices as user attributes ? or should we handle them at AWS IoT offering ?*
3. Authentication & Authorization of users and devices - *Again Cognito*
4. Secure MQTT broker service for communication between device and users - *AWS IoT seems to be matching, however I am not very much aware on configuring them and setting up user level access controls through API's. Can we use AWS IoT here ?*

Comment: Your question is very general, please provide more information about the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Device provisioning can be generally done in three ways:

1. Manually, by defining an IoT things in IoT Services. Certificates should be placed on IoT devices.
2. By using AWS IoT SDKs. AWS Credentials (or Temporary Security Credentials) is needed.
3. Using AWS CLI.

In IoT services, you can put devices together by adding them in a same group. User can access to the IoT device's data in two ways:

1. IoT devices save data in Databases and user can access databases and retrieve data.
2. Defining the application(Mobile App, ...) as an IoT device and putting it in the same group, so the application can subscribe/publish to the topics of different devices. Consider that, all IoT devices have credentials (CA, private and public key) which should be place on IoT devices and it will be needed during communication with AWS Broker. Also the policies for each device should be attached correctly.